# div not displaying when hovered another div

Tags: html, css

i think that i have forgotten my css but i have a problem

here is my code

```
   <div class="footer_container">
     <div class="website_logo_to_footerexpand"></div>

     <div class="info_cont">
       <div class="info_slide_arrow"></div><!--arrow-->

       <div class="info_slide">
         <div class="level1">&copy; Datacardz.Inc <?php echo date('Y'); ?></div>
         <div class="level2">
            <a href="" id="about" class="href_link">About</a>
            <a href="" id="terms" class="href_link">Terms</a>
            <a href="" id="corporate" class="href_link">Company</a>
           <a href="" id="blog" class="href_link">Blog</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

the problem is that when i use the css code:- website_logo_to_footerexpand:hover ~ .info_cont it displays the div but it vanishes as soon as i nove the mouse to the info_cont div

and the code .website_logo_to_footer_expand:hover > .info_cont does not work at all

my css ----

```
.website_logo_to_footerexpand{
float:left;
cursor:pointer;
background-image:url(data_cardz_imagesprites.png);
background-position:0 0;
width:60px;
height:60px;
}
.info_cont{
float:left;
height:60px;
opacity:0;
visibility:hidden;
}

.website_logo_to_footerexpand:hover ~ .info_cont{
visibility:visible;
opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: where is the rest of the CSS?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve here? hover over what for what?

Comment: hover over .website_logo_to_footerexpand to display .info_cont but info_cont vanishes as soon as i move the mouse from .website_logo_to_footerexpand to .info_cont

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/K4Mp4/1/

Check the demo please.

```
.website_logo_to_footerexpand{
float:left;
cursor:pointer;
background-image:url(data_cardz_imagesprites.png);
background-position:0 0;
width:60px;
height:60px;
}
.info_cont{
float:left;
height:60px;
opacity:0;
visibility:hidden;
}

.footer_container:hover > .info_cont{
visibility:visible;
opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be putting the hover on `.footer_container` not `.website_logo_to_footer_expand` that class is to the left so naturally when you scroll out of it the info will disappear

```
.footer_container:hover > .info_cont
```

you also need to add a `clearfix` because you are floating elements inside `.footer_container`

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `display:block;` for floated child divs and `display:inline-block;` for the parent div then the hovering effect will work